# How to ready multiple rows from json file in Jmeter

Tags: java, json, jmeter, automated-tests, load-testing

I'm new in Jmeter I'm generating the random data in json file (say for n no of requests).

these are  requests in the json file
`{"firstName":"Colton","lastName":"Alvarez","password":"K42mC7UQ","email":"Robert2@test.COM","orgName":"Alist","locationName":"Stillwell Avenue","address1":"Stillwell Avenue","address2":"11Stillwell Avenue","city":"San Francisco","state":"South Dakota","country":"United States","zipCode":"12901","orgEmail":"Gavin@test.COM"}`

`{"firstName":"Stella","lastName":"Barrera","password":"BUiVwvAw","email":"Alex3@test.COM","orgName":"Quicker Consulting","locationName":"Cove Lane","address1":"Cove Lane","address2":"8Cove Lane","city":"Miami","state":"North Carolina","country":"United States","zipCode":"26257","orgEmail":"Anthony@test.COM"}`

`{"firstName":"Violet","lastName":"Trujillo","password":"O5belqdN","email":"London1@test.COM","orgName":"Buapel Limited","locationName":"Ford Street","address1":"Ford Street","address2":"21Ford Street","city":"Miami","state":"California","country":"United States","zipCode":"72159","orgEmail":"Thomas@test.COM"}`

`{"firstName":"Aubrey","lastName":"Tyler","password":"Qj32XyDE","email":"Julian4@test.COM","orgName":"Yrsa Associates","locationName":"Summer Place","address1":"Summer Place","address2":"9Summer Place","city":"New York","state":"Maryland","country":"United States","zipCode":"19250","orgEmail":"Cooper@test.COM"}`

`{"firstName":"Emily","lastName":"Gilliam","password":"TNKqqqfX","email":"London5@test.COM","orgName":"Alist","locationName":"Washington Walk","address1":"Washington Walk","address2":"19Washington Walk","city":"New York","state":"Massachusetts","country":"United States","zipCode":"90694","orgEmail":"Tristan@test.COM"}`

now i want jmeter to take this data as request body to hit the n no of threads

**Problem is when i put the data for single request in json file it read it and give me sucess. but when multiple row data is been put in json it try to take the whole data in request.**
[image: picking file in jmeter]
However i want jmeter to pick data from json one by one for every request not the same.

Comment: Not sure about jmeter but data you posted was not correct json format, updated the correct format for json array. Try using that

Comment: this is the right format it contains the multiple record request not array of requests example req thread 1 
{"firstName":"Colton","lastName":"Alvarez","password":"K42mC7UQ","email":"Robert2@test.COM","orgName":"Alist","locationName":"Stillwell Avenue","address1":"Stillwell Avenue","address2":"11Stillwell Avenue","city":"San Francisco","state":"South Dakota","country":"United States","zipCode":"12901","orgEmail":"Gavin@test.COM"}


req thread 2 

{"firstName":"Stella","lastName":"Barrera","password":"BUiVwvAw","email":"Alex3@test.COM" ..................}
.

Comment: But then you are storing in .json file. And if you are storing it in a json file and read from it, this data will not parse to json.

Comment: so if i store in the txt will jmeter will pick it one by one as json request ?

Comment: and i try with txt as well the problem is same

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it's because [__FileToString() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) reads **the whole file** into the request body, if you have a separate JSON body payload on a new line in the file you might want to use [__StringFromFile() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) instead which reads next line from the given file each time it's being called.

Also if the data is really "random" you can even proceed with a single test data "placeholder", for example change it to look like:

```
{
  "firstName": "${__groovy(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(6),)}",
  "lastName": "${__groovy(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(10),)}",
  "password": "${__groovy(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(8),)}",
  "email": "${__groovy(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(6),)}@test.COM",
  "orgName": "${__groovy(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(6),)}",
  "locationName": "${__groovy(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(20),)}",
  "address1": "${__groovy(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(20),)}",
  "address2": "${__groovy(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(20),)}",
  "city": "${__groovy(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(10),)}",
  "state": "${__groovy(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(10),)}",
  "country": "${__groovy(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(8),)}",
  "zipCode": "${__groovy(orgorg.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(5),)}",
  "orgEmail": "${__groovy(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(6),)}@test.COM"
}
```

and [wrap your __FileToString() function into __eval() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables/) like:

```
${__eval(${__FileToString(test.json,,)})}
```

this way you will get random values on each and every request